# How to manage TLS termination for a large number of certificates on AWS to a single ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer

We have customers that provision custom certificates with us for load balancing requests to their network (think similar to a CDN where you may front delivery of requests to a customer's upstream with a custom CNAME).

Today, we are using Nginx with a NLB to terminate all inbound TLS requests to our network and so there's no issue with provisioning as many certificates as we want.

We are exploring moving this solution to something that's completely managed (e.g. we are not running Nginx and managing EC2 instances).

My first thought was to use the ALB to terminate TLS however the ALB has a limit of 25 certificates. This would mean we have to use many ALBs which has cost and management overhead issues.

I'm also not sure that [SAN](https://repost.aws/questions/QUOPHCTQ0mR5aFIqgG0ACmWQ/absolute-maximum-number-of-certificates-for-application-load-balancer) for certificates is appropriate since each customer has their own, independent certificate and we don't want to leak adjacent customer details.

What other hosted (ideally AWS native) solutions are there for terminating TLS and routing the requests to an ALB that will scale to thousands of custom certificates?